# full-text search does not work with MATCH() and AGAINST()

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried full text search by postgresql with this code

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE MATCH (discription) AGAINST ('remote controller');
```

name of column is "discription"

keyword is "remote controller"

error message is here

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "AGAINST"
1: ...LECT * FROM test_table WHERE MATCH (discription) AGAINST ('...
```

I can not figure out what's wrong??

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) did you find that `match()` or `against()` are valid?

Comment: You are using MySQL syntax in a Postgres database.  No wonder you are getting a syntax error.  Look in the Postgres docs on how to do full text search.

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon Linoff said, you are using MySQL syntax in Postrgres. The alternative query for Pstgreses is the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test_table
WHERE to_tsvector(discription) @@ to_tsquery('remote controller');
```

In a nutshell... the **ts_vector** data type is provided for storing preprocessed documents (is a sorted list of distinct lexemes, which are words that have been normalized to merge different variants of the same word). When the **tsquery** is used to represent processed queries.

more information you can find in the following links:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-SEARCH
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch.html

**Note**: to improve the search performance you can use also index on this:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/textsearch-tables.html#TEXTSEARCH-TABLES-INDEX

Answer (score 0):

This query will work:

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE 
difference(discription, 'remote controller') > 2;
```

The Soundex system is a method of matching similar-sounding names by converting them to the same code.

The soundex function converts a string to its Soundex code. The difference function converts two strings to their Soundex codes and then reports the number of matching code positions. Since Soundex codes have four characters, the result ranges from zero to four, with zero being no match and four being an exact match.

**NOTE** : the difference function gives the difference between the soundex code  of two string.